# Iterating through dataframes in a list using for loops

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I am new to pandas/python. So i am reading a .xlsx file and in that i created bunch of dataframes, 16 to be precise and a master dataframe which is empty. Now I want to append all of these 16 dataframes to the master dataframe one by one, using for loops.

1 method I thought of iterating through a list. But can these df_1, df_2 etc be stored in a list, and then we can iterate over them.

Let's say suppose i had a csv file then,

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv('---.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('---.csv')
```

then i create a list,

```
filenames = ['---.csv','---.csv']
```

create an empty master dataframe :

```
master_df= []
```

finally, loop through the list :

```
for f in filenames:
    master_df.append(pd.read_csv(f))
```

but this wont apply, i need something similar, so how can i iterate over all the dataframes. Any solution would be appreciated.

FINALLY, this is my master_df :

```
master_df = pd.DataFrame({'Variable_Name': [], 'Value':[], 'Count': []})
```

and this is the 1st dataframe :

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Variable_Name': ['Track', 'Track', 'Track', 'Track'],
    'Value': ['Track 38','Track 39', 'Track 40', 'Track 37'], 
    'Count': [161, 160, 158, 152]})
```

Similarly 15 more are there.

Answer (score 0):

This is because *append()* returns new dataframe and this object should be stored somewhere

Try:

```
for f in filenames:
    master_df = master_df.append(pd.read_csv(f))
```

More info of append function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html